# Router supervisor strategy in config

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Is it possible(and how) to specify supervisor strategy of router in config file? All examples show how to do this in programmatic way. My router is get configured from config file. It also will be good if router config is in file, but supervisor strategy will be configured in code.

Another question how the things changes if I use cluster aware routers? Is it possible to provide supervisor strategy for such kind of routers

PS. One more question that doesn't relate to supervision: is it possible to pass a constructor parameter to all routees of a pooled cluster aware router, and how(if possible)?

Comment: Please post the answer if you have found it.
From what I read and code I saw, setting supervision strategy in Config and reading it is not possible.    
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html   http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/fault-tolerance.html